# segmentation fault in pthread_join

Tags: c, pthreads

I have a problem with this, because in the moment of get a response in the `pthread_join` the program have a segmentation fault, and I don't have idea how to solve this problem.

Here is my code:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct matricez{
    int matriz;
    int multiplica;
};

void* multiplicacion(void* estructura){
    struct matricez* valores=(struct matricez*)estructura;
    int uno=valores->matriz;
    int dos=valores->multiplica;
    int tres=uno*dos;
        printf("entre y saque %d \n",tres); 
    return (void*)tres;
}

int main(int argc,char* argv[]){
    if(argc!=3){
        printf("Ingrese las dimensiones de fila y columna de la matriz");
        exit(1);
    }
    int filas=atoi(argv[1]);
    int columnas=atoi(argv[2]);
    pthread_t id[filas*filas];
    int matriz[filas][columnas];
    int multiplica[filas][columnas];
    int resultado[filas][columnas];
    int i;
    int j;
    for(i=0;i<filas;i++){           
        for(j=0;j<columnas;j++){
            matriz[i][j]=rand()%11;
            multiplica[i][j]=rand()%11;
            printf("posicion %d,%d=%d \n",i,j,matriz[i][j]);
            printf("posicion %d,%d=%d \n",i,j,multiplica[i][j]);            
        }   
    }
    struct matricez valores;
    int hilo=0;
    for(i=0;i<filas;i++){
        for(j=0;j<columnas;j++){
            valores.matriz=matriz[i][j];
            valores.multiplica=multiplica[i][j];
            pthread_create(&id[hilo],NULL,multiplicacion,&valores);
            pthread_join(id[hilo],(void*)resultado[i][j]);
            hilo++;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: pthread_join(id[hilo],(void*)&resultado[i][j]); this solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

In your code, `resultado[i][j]` is an `int` (normally 4 bytes), which is casted to `(void *)` (normally 8 bytes).

You probably want to change the type of `resultado` to `int *resultado[filas][columnas];`
Then change the `join` code to `pthread_join(id[hilo],(void*) &resultado[i][j]);`. Don't forget the '&' there because you need a pointer.

PS:
1. You should see this warning by the compiler, don't ignore that.

```
warning: cast to 'void *' from smaller integer type 'int' [-Wint-to-void-pointer-cast]
```

2. Try not to use non-English as variable names, especially for asking questions...